# How to calculate xy difference?

Tags: c++, math, gps, arduino

I know this might be silly but excuse me. I have a gps module that I converted the latitude and longitude to xy and I have another point for example: 33.12, 55.12.

What I need it to know is how could I know the difference between the 2 points and if I have the speed of my gps, could I be able to know when I will reach it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On short distances you can ignore the earth's curvature and go with Pythagorean theorem.
On larger scale you need to remember that earth is a sphere.
Theory and examples with some java here:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html